# what is the correct way of checking character(alphabetic) data entry in R?

Tags: r

Suppose I want a user of my R program to enter a positive number.

If he enters a negative or types any alphabet (a, b ,c, d, etc.), I would want to keep him trying until he enters the desired positive number.

How do I check if he enters a character (a, b, c, etc.)?

For example if I have:(In fact someone on this site helped me to write this code correctly but I do not understand certain things especially, the third line as I have indicated `"#explanation of this line"` in the code

```
n <- -1
while(is.na(n) | (n < 1)  ){
  n <- readline("enter a positive integer for the number of simulations: ")
  n <- ifelse(grepl("\\D",n),-1,as.integer(n)) #explanation of this line
}
```

QUESTIONS:

1. I know that `is.na(n)` means if n is null (not available) so if the user presses enter `is.na(n)` becomes `TRUE`. Is that correct?
2. what is the meaning of: `n <- ifelse(grepl("\\D",n),-1,as.integer(n)`?
3. How do I check if the user enters (a, b, c, d, ...)?

Thanks to those who can come to my rescue.

Owusu Isaac

Answer (score 5):

See `?regex` and `?grep`, and my answer you copied the code from.

Q1 : if the user just presses enter, n becomes `""`, which, when turned into an integer, will become NA.

```
> n <- ""
> as.integer(n)
[1] NA
```

Q2 : `grepl` is a function that checks whether values in a vector fit a regular expression (`?regex`) and returns a logical vector. In this case, the regular expression is `"\\D"`. `\D` means anything that is not a digit, including a negative sign or a dot. The backslash has to be escaped, so that's why it is double. So if it fits anything that's not a digit, n will become -1. Now "" doesn't fit anything, so n would become as.integer(n) and hence NA (see Q1).

Q3 : for checking letters, you can use -again- regular expressions, or `%in% letters` :

```
> n <- "a"
> grepl("[a-z]",n)
[1] TRUE
> n %in% letters
[1] TRUE
```

Or, if you want to have both lower case and upper case :

```
> n <- c("a","A")
> grepl("[[:alpha:]]",n)
[1] TRUE TRUE
> grepl("(?i)[a-z]",n)
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

These are only some of the possibilities. Read the help files I refer to thoroughly and play around with it for a while. Regular expressions are very powerful once you get the hang of it.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to learn regular expressions (but you *should*) then this code would do the same task:

```
n<--1
while(is.na(n) | (n < 1)  ){
  n <- readline("enter a positive integer for the number of simulations: ")
  if( !is.integer(as.integer(n)) ) {n <- -1} else { 
                                   n <- as.integer(n) }
}
```

Comment: Hi DWin, many thanks for your help. I copied the code into R and it gave me an unlimited loop. But I will play with it

Comment: Sorry. It was missing a "!" before the antecedent expression. Or you could reverse the order of the consequent expressions. Should be fixed.

Comment: if you do `n<- as.integer(n) ; if(!is.integer(n)) n <- -1´ it should be sufficient, but it's not answering OPs question of course.